# \setfloatadjustment does not work for tables in latex memoir class

Tags: tables, memoir, fontsize

I am typing my thesis in `memoir` class. I would like to set all tables in `\small`. I tried what the manual said :

```
\setfloatadjustment{table}{\small\centering\sffamily}
```

Both `\centering` and `\sffamily` worked, but not the font size, Any suggestions?

Here is MWE. Thanks :)

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\setfloatadjustment{table}{\small\centering\sffamily}
\begin{document}

This is a pragraph. gfhsufhsduhsdusdf hudf sfuhf. This is a pragraph. gfhsufhsduhsdusdf hudf sfuhf.df hudf sfuhf.df hudf sfuhf.df hudf sfuhf.

\begin{table}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline 
    sds & sds & ssdfd \\ 
    \hline 
    djfndjf asdf & fgjgs g &  gsdgsdf \\ 
    \hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure? Try `\tiny`, it's a bit easier to see

Comment: @daleif - I can replicate the OP's issue, on both MacTeX2016 and MacTeX2017/pre, `memoir 2016/05/16 v3.7f`. I.e., both `\centering` and `\sffamily` work as expected, but the switches to change the relative font size -- I tried both `\small` and `\tiny` -- do not.

Comment: @Mico: I've the impression that none of the font size switches works

Comment: I think the cause of this is the explicit `\normalsize` at the end of `\@xfloat` definition in `\AtBeginDocument{...}` in `memoir.cls`.  The font family change and other changes persist, but the font size is reset. You can use `\show\@xfloat` after `\setfloatadjustment` and again inside `\begin{table}...\end{table}` -- the definitions differ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my point of view this is a 'bug' of `memoir`.

The `memoir.cls` does

```
\let\mem@old@xfloat\@xfloat
\def\@xfloat#1[#2]{\mem@old@xfloat{#1}[#2]\@nameuse{#1adjustment}}
```

whereas `\setfloatadjustment{table}{...}` defines `tableadjustment`, for example.

Now, there's a piece of code at lines 2380ff

```
\AtBeginDocument{
  \let\m@m@xfloat\@xfloat
  \def\@xfloat #1[#2]{%
    \m@m@xfloat #1[#2]%
    \def\baselinestretch{\m@m@float@spacing}%
    \normalsize}
}
```

which grabs the already redefined `\x@float` (with `\@nameuse{#1adjustment`) which is correct, but at the end says `\normalsize`, so any font size switches are reverted.

A bypass solution could be an additional redefinition of `\@xfloat` or a patch or saying

`\setfloatadjustment{table}{\small\centering\sffamily\let\normalsize\relax}`

for example.

Comment: Thanks, for the analysis, I'll fix that for the next release

Comment: Perhaps there should be a query whether a `#1adjustment` exists for the relevant float type and if this is the case, drop the `\normalsize` then?

Comment: Thank you guys :) appreciated it. Christian's fix worked: \setfloatadjustment{table}{\small\centering\sffamily\let\normalsize\relax}
@daleif - thanks for  maintaining the memoir package :)

Comment: I think the best solution would be to move the `\@nameuse{#1adjustment}` part into the cited `\AtBeginDocument` part **after** `\normalsize`. The `\normalsize` does not hurt and is probably necessary because of the change to `\baselinestretch`

Comment: @daleif: Yes, that's a good idea.